# Can I grant access to objects owned by another account in AWS S3 using bucket policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to control access to an object, which is created by another AWS account. Can I do that by bucket policies?
In other words, **does bucket policies apply to objects that are owned by another account?**

I do not have 2 AWS accounts so I can not test this case in action.

Comment: Creating multiple AWS accounts is very easy with [AWS Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The ability to grant access to objects can only be done from the Account that owns the bucket/object.

If you think about it, this makes sense -- you would not want me granting access to your objects. Only the account that owns the bucket/object can do this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can by creating a policy. Please find a sample policy below,

```js
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example permissions",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-ID:root"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

You can do it through AWS console, CLI or API. Please find CLI sample below,

```
aws s3 ls s3://examplebucket --profile AccountBadmin
aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket examplebucket --profile AccountBadmin
```

Please read documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html) for more details

Comment: Bucket-level permissions (e.g. ListBucket), yes, but object-level permissions (e.g. GetObjects), no. Your example works, but is only half of the problem.  The owner account A of a bucket cannot grant object access to account B when the objects were uploaded by account C, because the objects are not owned by account A.  A probable exception to this is if the objects were uploaded with `x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control` or an equivalent non-canned ACL giving account A (the bucket owner) full control of the objects.

Comment: Even if the objects are uploaded using the canned acl 'bucket-owner-full-control' the owner remains the same(the uploader) and the bucket owner cannot control access using bucket policies.

Comment: @Schleir AWS currently supports changing ownership through a bucket policy with the 'bucket-owner-full-control' canned ACL provided when the object is created. This is a new feature called S3 Object Ownership: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/about-object-ownership.html